# Exception: Request failed for 'url here' returned code 400

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a couple of scripts that I'm currently using to call API's to fetch data from. They all work perfectly except for one.

I keep getting the following error message:

`Exception: Request failed for 'url here' returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|281ea835-410... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

The API's all use the GET method and accept certain additional parameters as Headers.

The code looks like this:

```
function apiCall(){

  const url = 'Https url here';

  const options = {

    'method' : 'GET',
      'headers' : {
        'key' : 'key here',
        'Id' : 'ID here',
        'cache-control' : 'no-cache'
               
      }
  } 

  var responce = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  var json = responce.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);

  //console.log(data);

}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this would be? There a six different endpoints I'm calling, all set up exactly the same. Only the one doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you're sending a bad request to 'url here'... assuming that you're not trying to connect to 'url here' via HTTPS and this is in fact a placeholder, without knowing the endpoint, API and required request parameters, there's not really much anyone can suggest.

Comment: Thanks @ Rafa Guillermo. I realised that after figuring out what the issue was. The Id parameter accepts an integer value. I was passing it without quotes as you do in general JS. After reading about and learning how to use 'muteHttpExceptions' it became pretty clear. User error on my part as you suggested. Another lesson learnt on my end. Thanks for the responce. I did leave a comment yesterday but doesnt seem to have updated here.